# windows phone - how to get picked picture name

Tags: c#, cordova, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

My windows phone hybrid app is picking one video from my gallery. 
My goal is to get the name of the selected video.

For this I am using a **FileOpenPicker** object and wrapping it inside my cordova/phonegap plugin.

I got to open my gallery and pick one video but when I select it I just receive this in my output windows:

```
*thread 0x87c terminated code 259 (0x103).*
*INFO: AppDeactivated because UserAction
program'[184] AgHost.exe' terminated with 0 (0x0).*
```

my plugin code:

```
 class PickVideo : BaseCommand, IFileOpenPickerContinuable
    {
    public void pickOneVideo(string options) {
        try {

            Debug.WriteLine("pickOneVideo --------------------------------");
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

            openPicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "GetOneVideo";
            openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue(); 
        }            
        catch (Exception e) {

            Debug.WriteLine("e: " + e.Message);
        }



        // return path video
        //DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "path del video"));
    }




    public void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("-- ContinueFileOpenPicker ---");
        if (args.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine( "Picked video: " + args.Files[0].Name);


        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(  "Operation cancelled.");
        }
    }
}
```

and I am using the same ContinuationManager as here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dn631755.aspx

So I would expect my control to enter into `ContinueFileOpenPicker()` where I could retrieve my video name.

What am I missing?

I am using `wp silverlight 8.1`, `cordova` and `vs2013`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here my working solution:

```
    public void pickOneVideo(string options) {
        try {

            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

            openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();

            view.Activated += viewActivated; 
        }            
        catch (Exception e) {

            Debug.WriteLine("e: " + e.Message);
        }



        // return path video
        //DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "path del video"));
    }

    private void viewActivated(CoreApplicationView sender, IActivatedEventArgs args1)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("viewActivated ----");
        FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;

        if (args != null)
        {
            if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;

            view.Activated -= viewActivated;
             Debug.WriteLine("args: " + args.Files[0].Name);
         }
    }
```